# Work around to create feature-linked annotation from standard annotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, annotation, relationship-class

I have one standard annotation feature class that I have used to label the contract names of 6 feature classes. I'm in a tough position where I've been asked to remove a few hundred records from about 2000 records spanning over the 6 different feature classes. This would create 200 orphaned annotations in my standard annotation feature class and I need to have the flexibility to bring these annotation back just in case. Since the labels are meant for a data driven map book, the labels and leader lines have been painstakingly positioned manually. I don't want to have to recreate all these labels as "feature-linked" because I would have to re-position them all.

Since the text field from the annotation layer has a corresponding text field in the feature classes, I should theoretically be able to create a link between the two with a relationship table. I have no idea how to do this or if it is even possible to retro-actively create a feature-linked annotation. Has anyone done this or have any answers on how to do this?

Comment: That sounds difficult, but not impossible. Annotations can have extra characters (line breaks, tabs etc..) that were not in the original field. I would suggest that you try to resolve them using .net then you can possibly definition query them out if you add a field for on/off that way they're not gone, just not shown.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "resolve them using .net". Do you mean create a join table for the contract names that I want to remove and join it to the annotation feature class...just like I would with the actual feature classes?

Comment: Take the text string, remove the carriage returns etc.. and select from the feature class then put the OID of the returned feature against the annotation, if not then that's one to do manually. Then don't remove the features if possible just definition query them out. It is possible to do this in python but would work much better in .net if that is an option - working with annotations in python isn't the best.